# create-react-app + Webpack 5 without ejecting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-5

Is there a way to overwrite the webpack version without ejecting?

I know [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts) or similar packages can be used to modify the webpack config without ejecting but can it replace the webpack with my chosen version?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's possible. Too many custom settings need to be configured manually.